# How to get BIG JSON data using php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON link which has a very big data. So, I couldn't parse it using  `json_decode($json);` for the way of `$json = file_get_contents('_LINK_ ')`, because it exceeds the **memory limit** although I changed it the memory_limit to `64M`. Therefore, I used the following way/code to parse it, which I got it from here `php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php`:

```
$json = @fopen("_URL", "r");

if ($json) {
   while (($json_data = stream_get_line($json, 4096)) !== false) {
       echo $json_data;
      //OR processing the $json_data
   }
}
if (!feof($json)) {
    echo "ERROR:...\n";
}
fclose($json);
```

and I did it sucessfully. This is an example of one of the `$json_data` echo'ed:

```
[{"A":"away team","C":"Competition name","D":"\/Date
(1561758400000)\/","H":"Home team","U":"hyperlink",...
}]
```

Now, I would like to get the `values` such as `away team, Competition name, \/Date(1561758400000)\/, Home team, hyperlink, ...`. So I used `var_dump(json_decode($json_data, true));`. It returned NULL

I have tried `$rows = json_decode($json_data);` inside the **while loop** in order to echo the `$row->A`, but I failed.

I also tried:

```
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($json_data as $row) {
  $a = $row['A'];
}
```

inside the **while loop**, but also failed because I guessed it's not decoded successfully.

My expectation is that I would like to convert the above JSON DATA/STRING to **array** or whatever way we can use so that I can get the values.

Again, I am okay with using the normal way of parsing json file by using `file_get_contents`.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE the returned array as per the comments for better understanding**:

```
[{"A":"Ukraine","C":"UEFA European Championship 2020",
"D":"\/Date(1567872000000)\/",
H":"Lithuania",
"NP":"",
"P":0,
"T":1,
"U":"hyperlink",
"V":1,"B1":22533,
"B2":22568,
"EE":[{"B":false,"C":13,"O":"","P":-1.5,"T":7},
    {"B":false,"C":1.001,"O":"","P":1.5,"T":8},
    {"B":false,"C":2.001,"O":"","P":1.8,"T":7},
    {the same as above}],
"HL":true,"I":198216465,
"S":"Football"},
{"A":"Moldova",...(to be continued the same as above)...
}],
"HL":true,
"I":198188444,
"S":"Football"
}]
```

Comment: [NULL is returned if the json](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

Comment: try `json_decode(data[0])` since it seems it is in an array.

Comment: You cannot decode an arbitrary section of a json string. You have to parse the whole thing. Is there any definite structure to it? Like it just being a big array? You could parse all the invidual values of that array... The example of the JSON you gave just doesn't tell me enough, but you've seen the whole thing, so you should know.

Comment: Check [json_last_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and [json_last_error_msg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: Change the memory limit to `128M` minimum or even `256M`

Comment: Is it one big single-level array of just objects `[{},{},{},....,{}]` ?

Comment: The `/` slashes are escaped `$json_data = json_decode(stripslashes($json),true);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: done, and waiting for the change.

Comment: You have to restart Apache to make the change active

Comment: @Arleigh Hix , I just updated the array for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: @ KIKO Software : I just added the json data for your better understanding and help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regularize your json

```
$json = '
    [
        {
            "A":"away team",
            "C":"Competition name",
            "D":"Date (1561758400000)",
            "H":"Home team",
            "U":"hyperlink"
        }
    ]';
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach ($json_data as $row) {
        echo $row['A'];
        echo $row['C'];
        echo $row['D'];
        echo $row['H'];
        echo $row['U'];
    }
```

Comment: it returns error: `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given`

Comment: Yeah my friend @Phung Ng, but the " \/ " sign broken your string and " ,... " broken your json

Comment: Noted, and how can we overcome it now, please?

Comment: Actually, I just need to get the values of the keys **"A", "C", "D", "H", "U"** only.

Comment: foreach ($json_data as $row) {
}

Comment: As you know, when i apply the `foreach` loop as per your suggestion, it returns error like `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. This is, I guessed, because i failed to decode the json data using `json_decode()` for the very important reason that some of the json strings do not have **double quotes** as in the UPDATED part above. Can you help me with this?